# Using Swig to Convert VARIANT Objects Back and Forth With Python

Tags: python, c, swig

Given a C function with the following signature:

```
extern  void* getDeviceInfo(void *device);
```

Note: the `void*` points to an array of unsigned shorts.

**What is the best practice** for presenting a list of integers to Python?

Comment: Can you add more detail? What exactly is the problem? Don't you just de-reference the pointer and then extract the values?

Comment: Show minimal complete example of the C usage of this function so we can figure out how to expose it to Python.